# Algebra Simplification (Statistics)

Tags: probability, statistics

I am working through a proof in a statistics course, and I am having trouble following one equality.

How is the following equality true?  $$n\left[\sum X_i^2-\frac{\left(\sum X_i\right)^2}{n}\right]=n\sum\left(X_i-\overline{X}\right)^2$$

I've tried expanding the right side, and a couple of "add zero" tricks.  I just can't seem to find the clever step required here.

Comment: Well, step one can simply be dividing both sides by $n$.

Comment: @Axoren perhaps that could be one step but it doesn't help to light the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from the right hand side:

$$n\sum(X_i-\bar{X})^2=n\sum(X_i^2-2X_i\bar{X}+\bar{X}^2)\\
=n\sum X_i^2 -2n\bar{X}\sum X_i+n\sum\bar{X}^2 \\
=n\sum X_i^2 -2n\bar{X}\sum X_i+n^2 (\bar{X})^2
\\=n\sum X_i^2 -2n\frac{\sum X_i}{n}\sum X_i+n^2 (\frac{\sum X_i}{n})^2\\
=n\sum X_i^2 +(\sum X_i)^2$$

which is the left hand side.

Comment: Thanks!  I was forgetting to square $n$ when I was looking at the sum of $\overline{X}^2$.